# LDAP authentication - avoid duplicate uidNumber

Tags: authentication, openldap, sssd, ldif

I have just successfully configured OpenLDAP Users authentication in a single CentOS6 box, based on SSSD. Took some time and many trials, but it's working.

Now, I want to start adding users. I'm doing it manually with `.ldif` files, based on reference from [Arch docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_authentication). The problem is - I might, by mistake, create 2 users with the same `uidNumber`. And that would cause strange results.

My question - is it possible to tell LDAP that `uidNumber` should be a unique property, and not add the user if this attribute value already existed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `unique` overlay to achieve this. See [chapter 12.16](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) of the OpenLDAP manual and `man slapo-unique` (unfortunately, both still only refer the old-style configuration in `slapd.conf`, not the `cn=config` online configuration).

Comment: Based on your reference, here's the solution (using legacy slapd.conf): 1. Uncomment `moduleload unique.la`  2. Add the following lines: `overlay unique` and `unique_uri ldap:///?uidNumber?sub?`